# Why the cell height is not changing on tapping the button once. It is working only when I tap the button twice

Tags: tableview

[Click Here To see the UI of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWOUH.png)

Here In the image you can see the ui.

--> There is a tableView & a button on the main view.

--> I have taken a custom tableViewCell class
    In the cell I have taken a UIView

Constraints Added To That View are: 
            centre horizontally, height, width, top & bottom constraint

I have added a outlet of the height constraint to the TVCell class

--> I have taken a button and added a event handler to it

--> Button Event handler:

In button event handler I am just changing the height of the view in the first cell and reloading the cell.

Now the problem is that height of the cell is changing when I tap on the button. But its happening only when I tap one the button twice. So I want to know why is it happening. Here I am adding my code below.

I have one solution for this problem which you can see after you see after the code of the ViewController & TableViewCell Class

VIEW CONTROLLER CLASS

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource{



    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.black
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }


    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        if cell.viewHeightConstraint.constant == 75 {
            cell.viewHeightConstraint.constant = 10
        }
        else{
            cell.viewHeightConstraint.constant = 75
        }

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath] , with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
    }

}
```

TABLEVIEWCELL CLASS

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        //Setting View Height To 75
        viewHeightConstraint.constant = 75

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }
}
```

You can get this source code from this link below

https://github.com/himansudev/tableViewIssue_15_4_20_1.git

Now I have a solution for this problem but I believe its not a proper solution. So what I have done is as shown below

1) I have modified the button event handler, see below is the modified code. Please refer to the above code to identify the changes that I have made to this event handler

```
  @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath] , with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
    }
```

2) Secondly I have added this extra piece of code , see below

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        print("viewDidLayoutSubviews")

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        if cell.viewHeightConstraint.constant == 75 {
            cell.viewHeightConstraint.constant = 10
        }
        else{
            cell.viewHeightConstraint.constant = 75
        }

    }
```

Find the source code after changes below

https://github.com/himansudev/tableViewSolution_15_4_20_1.git

Now after doing these two changes it is working (but sometimes it doesn't work when I tap on the button rapidly many times) but the problem is the viewDidLayoutSubviews() is not getting called but when I comment it than the cell is not working as expected .

SO I want to know why is it behaving that way???

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add also the **UITableViewDelegate** to your ViewController and a var like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var cellHeight: CGFloat = 75
```

and the heightForRow function which will return the right Height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeight
}
```

Then on your button action:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {        

    if cellHeight == 75 {

        cellHeight = 10
    }
    else{

        cellHeight = 75
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Also remove the constraint viewHeightConstraint because you do not need it.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering the question but the problem is I know this method & my doubt is why the code that I have written is not working properly and here achieving the task is not my goal my goal is to understand its unexpected behaviour. Thanks again

Comment: Because you try to expand and collapse a cell with a constraint without using a class to say what is the new height of the Cell. So the contentView does not changed. Always have to re-height the Cell after expand and collapse. The Cell height it is not change just using the constant of a height View. Imagine that the cell is 10px and you try to make it 75px without call the heightForRow to change the Cell height.